absolute path in firebase.json hosting.public
How can I use an absolute path to store the content to deploy?
I tried next config, but does not work:
      "target": "site",
      "public": "/tmp/dist",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],

The error says: Error: Directory '/tmp/dist' for Hosting does not exist.
I can do ls /tmp/dist and the folder exists. In fact, if I create a link in the project ln -s /tmp/dist dist, the deployment works with no problem.
The project is a multi-site project, so looks like I can not use the -p parameter:
$ firebase deploy -p /tmp/dist --only hosting:site

Error: Cannot specify --public option with multi-site configuration.

Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help


From a quick browse of the source code of the Firebase CLI the public path value is always handled through this:
path.normalize(path.join(this.projectDir, pathName))

Based on that it seems that you can only specify a relative path, not an absolute path.

Do you think that there is a reason? Maybe to have a look and create a PT  makes sense.

I'm not sure what a PT is nor whether the Firebase CLI intentionally only allows relative paths. All I did was look at the code so that I could answer answer your question, and based on that it seems that the Firebase CLI will only handle relative paths for the public property in the firebase.json file.
